# Components not animating with react-transition-group, just updates instantly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to animate a sidebar component following the first section on [this page](https://css-tricks.com/animating-between-views-in-react/#article-header-id-1). When I follow this the component doesn't animate, but simply mounts/unmounts.

The component `SidePage` is as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group"
import "./sidePage.css"

class SidePage extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("will mount")
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("did mount")
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("will unmount")
  }
  render() {
    const { content, sidePageOpen } = this.props
    return (
      <TransitionGroup component={null}>
        {sidePageOpen && (
          <CSSTransition key={content.id} classNames="sidepage" timeout={2000}>
            <div
              key={content.id}
              className="sidepage"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content.html }}
            />
          </CSSTransition>
        )}
      </TransitionGroup>
    )
  }
}

export default SidePage
```

and the css file:

```
.sidepage-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.sidepage-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.sidepage-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidepage-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.sidepage {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

Basic stuff I think — the `sidePageOpen` is a boolean state passed down, I have a button on another page that toggles this state. If anyone has any ideas/suggestions that would be brilliant and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the opacity property from sidepage class.

```
.sidepage {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.4; // remove me
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

The element get's added with a class of sidepage which has a opacity of 0.4, thats whats breaking the animation. Working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/40k9ol858w)

Comment: I did try this and have tried it again just now but it doesn't seem to work — I think it's something to do with Gatsby and how it's set up, thank you for pointing this out though.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found the solution — I had a styled `<Wrapper>` div created using emotion.sh styled components, I was using this to contain all of my content, not sure why but this didn't allow any animations — changing this to a simple `<div>` seemed to fix it.

Edit: Probably because it was recreating the Wrapper component on every state change.